# How to evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \ln (1+\frac1n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone help me evaluate the sum of this series through elementary means?
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n-1} \ln \left(1+\frac1n\right)$$

Comment: Since $1+\frac 1n=\frac{n+1}{n}$ we have $$\ln(1+\tfrac 1n)=\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)$$ which may be of some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the logarithm of the [Wallis product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product), hence such a series converges to $\color{red}{\log\frac{\pi}{2}}$.