# Test for convergence of the series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n,$ where $u_n=(-1)^{n-1}\ln\left(\frac n{n+1}\right).$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let: $v_n=\ln\left(\frac n{n+1}\right).$ I tried *Leibniz's test* and found out that although $$\lim_{n\to\infty} v_n=0$$ but

$v_{n+1}-v_n=\ln\left[\frac{(n+1)^2}{n(n+2)}\right]=\ln\left(1+\frac1{n^2+2n}\right)\ge 0\implies v_{n+1}\ge v_n.$ So no conclusion can be made here. I also tried *Absolute convergence test* and found out that the series: $\sum |u_n|$ diverges to $\infty.$ That means it's of no use.

What else can I try? Please suggest... Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can apply the alternating series test. Since $\ln\left (\frac n{n+1}\right)$ is monotone and tends to zero, the alternating series $\sum (-1)^{n-1}\ln\left (\frac n{n+1}\right)$ converges. EDIT: Ah, I now see from googling that the Leibniz test is the same as the alternating series test. I guess your troubled by the fact that $\ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$ isn't decreasing? But you can note that $(-1)^{n-1}\ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right) = (-1)^n\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)$.

Comment: How fool I am! Thanks

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238816/how-to-evaluate-sum-limits-n-1-infty-1n-1-ln-1-frac1n/1238825#1238825

Answer (score 1):

Define $v_n=-\log\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)$. Then your series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nv_n$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}v_n=0$ and $(v_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is decreasing. So, you *can* apply the Leibniz test.

Comment: Oh yes, since $v_n$ is increasing so we can take $b_n=\lim v_n -v_n$ to make $b_n$ a decreasing function and..... Thank you sir.